# Shopify email-merge

Tags: shopify, liquid

Is it possible to merge emails using Shopify's API?

This is the liquid code I tried:

```
{% for email in customer.emails %}

{{ customer_email.first_name }}

or {{ customer_email.phone }}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. You don't tell what is the problem with the code provided. Could you add this information to your question.

Comment: Are you looping inside email? No, no, no! For tag in collections tags... For tag in customer tags...